# Knowing if a gotoAndPlay is ready

Tags: actionscript-3

I have like little stories in flash, wich have 1 object speaking on each frame.

If you click the object, it tells something (like the first frame is, hello my name is ...)
This is done with gotoandplay.

Example: personFrame1.mouth.gotoAndPlay(2); 
This will make his mouth move and speak for a short amount of time.

I'm having 1 issue, i can click multiple times on the object (within like 2 seconds) so it speaks a few times, interchangeably.

Is there a way to check if the gotoAndPlay is ready, and then make it possible to click again?
So there is only 1 speech at the same time

Answer (score 2):

```
if (!personFrame1.mouth.isPlaying) personFrame1.mouth.gotoAndPlay(2);
```

This will check if your person's mouth is still "moving", that is, the MC is still playing, and will not initiate another play sequence until "mouth" won't stop.

Comment: Damn it's really that simple. Thx!